# à te regarder = en te regardant ? (à + infinitif -> gérondif)

Tags: constructions, infinitif, gérondif

Cette question est provoquée par le livre [*Je t'aime tant* par Caroline Pellissier et Virginie Aldjidi](https://www.babelio.com/livres/Pellissier-Je-taime-tant/1448363). Il s'agit d'une histoire pour les enfants, assez répétitive, ou chaque strophe/vers finit avec l'énoncé comme :

> Et à te regarder, si mignon, Je t'aimerais tant...

(le seul mot qui change est l'adjectif : mignon -> agile, doué, curieux, frêle, désolé, impatient, gai.)

Ma question est : est-ce qu'il est correct de le rendre en utilisant un gérondif :

> et en te regardant (être) si mignon, je t'aimerais tant...

?

Dans certains des vers l'adjectif porte sur l'action, donc il pourrait s'agir aussi de phrases comme :

> et en te regardant courir derrière un papillon, je t'aimerais tant...

En outre : est-ce qu'on est justifié à utiliser le gérondif ici : de point de vue grammatical et de point de vue du sens ? Est-ce que *à + infinitif* plus naturel quand suivi d'un nom/adjectif, alors que gérondif est mieux quand il est suivi par un verbe ?

Answer (score 5):

Grammaticalement les 2 formes sont correctes, et le sens reste voisin. Mais à mon avis, il y a une différence un peu subtile :

- *en te regardant* insiste sur la circonstance, la simultanéité, on pourrait le rapprocher de *quand je te regarde*
- *à te regarder* introduit presque une causalité ; le *je t'aimerais* est présenté comme une conséquence de ce que vois

Mais je reconnais qu'il s'agit d'une lecture un peu personnelle ...

Comment: Pas si personnelle que ça, j'ai le même ressenti.